# Can't open some DBF files in PHP

Tags: php, visual-foxpro, dbf, dbase

I have a php script that uses **dbase** to open dbf files.
I found that I can't open some of this files and I don't know why.

The error that I got is:

> dbase_open(): unable to open database

But I can open other files without problem.

I've tried open it with DBF Viewer and then exporting it again and it works then, but I can't do that with php.

I don't know if it could be a charset problem or a version problem, but files seem equal, in Visual FoxPro.

What should i check?

Comment: Highlight code & correct spelling

Comment: Ok, thank you, i'm starting to think that it is a problem with a timestamp column

Comment: Can you extract and provide a [mcve]? Without that, I'm afraid this question isn't of much use here and the possible advise rather generic (check spelling, check permissions, check file format/version).

Comment: I wonder if dbase_open() can handle VFP 9 tables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a column with type **Timestamp** dbase for php doesn't allow this type.
The solution was convert timestamp to date